# Open an app from within, by using the bundle identifier

Tags: ios, swift, bundle, in-app

Typically I would use some sort of public URL to open an app from within another app but all I was given were the bundle IDs of the apps I'm supposed to open.  Is there a way to do this?  This is the function I was using to open outside apps from within an app:

```
 var appStoreURL: URL?

func openAppFromMenu(inAppURL: URL?, appStoreURL: URL?) {

if inAppURL != nil {

    if let inApp = inAppURL {
        if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(inApp)
        {
            UIApplication.shared.openURL(inApp)
        } else {
            //redirect to safari because the user doesn't have in app
            print("App not installed")
            self.appStoreURL = appStoreURL
            addAlert()

        }
    }
} else {
    //redirect to safari because the user doesn't in app
    print("App not installed")
    self.appStoreURL = appStoreURL
    addAlert()
}
```

}

Comment: [Search online](http://www.gotschemes.com/) for the URL-scheme for said app, contact the author or try [reverse engineering it](http://resources.infosecinstitute.com/ios-application-security-part-30-attacking-url-schemes/)

Answer (score 0):

No, if the app isn't in your app group and it doesn't have a public URL, you can't open it.

Comment: What do you mean by in my app group.  We have access to the apps and those who created them

Comment: Have them create URL schemes then.